# 100% Rye Pizza Base Recipes?

Tags: dough, pizza, italian-cuisine, low-carb, rye

I'm looking for a 100% rye pizza base recipe. The recipes I can find all combine the rye with other flours (typically wheat based). I know it is possible to create 100% rye based pizza bases as I know of one pizza place in town that sells them.

I understand that they had to do something special to keep the pizza base from falling apart. I don't mind experimenting a bit to find a recipe that works, but I could use some ideas on where to start - what sort of ingredients might bind the rye so that it doesn't crumble as a thin pizza base and maintains a low glycemic index for my diabetic wife.

The only dietary requirements would be that the various ingredients maintain a low glycemic index or a specific ingredient with a high glycemic index can be counteracted by some other ingredient. And only using rye flour.

Comment: 1) I added rye and low-carb instead of low-gi. We already have the 2nd tag, and it suits the general category without being overly technical.  2) What are your exact dietary restrictions; it might determine what people suggest as binders. 3) Welcome to the site...

Comment: I edited your post to make it a bit more concise.  There's no need to greet people every question (though this is your first!), or to thank them: that's what we're all here for.  I also removed the tag request, since it's completed, and the note that you are using these at home (there's no commercial restriction here anyway). If you don't like any of the changes, just click edit in the lower left of your post and add it back, no problem.

Comment: This is a little close to a recipe request, though I think with a little editing all traces of recipe request can be removed.  This can become an excellent discussion of how to put together a rye based pizza dough.  If you're not sure what I mean about recipe requests, see meta:  http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4/should-i-need-a-recipe-for-x-questions-be-off-topic

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using 100% rye bread as your beginning and going from there, rather than pizza crust?  Peter Reinhart's [Bread Baker's Apprentice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1580082688) has a 100% rye sourdough bread that might suit your needs, although it will be a time consuming process.  A preview is online in [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=yHGBOXSNogsC&pg=PA239&lpg=PA239&dq=100%25+Sourdough+Rye+Bread+-+Peter+Reinhart&source=bl&ots=tVLYhXGuI_&sig=vcLN5p88fgZpf7smLxtlM3TA_gE&hl=en&ei=de9jTOboLsX7lwfr0NiZAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false).  The recipe is similar to a Neopolitan pizza dough - just basic ingredients with no fat.  Because of this, I'd roll out the pizza very thin, New York style, for a crackling crisp crust.  If you don't want to buy the book, many local libraries carry it in the US, at least.

Comment: Reinhart also has a new book out on wholegrain breads which may give even more info about how to work efficiently with 100% rye doughs.

Comment: @bikeboy - I got this book over the holiday season.  I didn't look in too much detail into the rye breads, but he does have new info on sourdough in there that's not in any of his other books.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't mind experimenting a bit to find a recipe that works, but I could use some ideas on where to start - what sort of ingredients might bind the rye so that it doesn't crumble as a thin pizza base and maintains a low glycemic index for my diabetic wife.

[Psyllium husk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psyllium_seed_husks) is the general go-to binder for low-carb bread, but I have not seen a recipe using it in rye pizza dough. Another alternative is to give up on substituting bread and use the same toppings with something else. A frittata does not add much extra work and works well with standard pizza toppings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work rye flour much longer than ordinary flour for the gluten to start binding the dough. I use a hand beater with dough hooks and start off with a very moist mix that includes olive oil and egg. Let it rise for a few hours then work more rye into the dough by hand kneading until it is nice and springy.

Answer (score 0):

Make a binder using hot water/rye flour combination and then combine it with a 100% rye sourdough.

Or increase the hydration to 96% in a sourdough rye and pour into a silicone round cake pan only 1/4 inch thick, let rise.  Bake and remove to cool. Top and bake again.  Just an idea but lets see what will work?  I too would like a rye pizza!

Rolling out 100% rye dough?  Lol!  Good one!

Answer (score 0):

We used this [recipe](https://www.acouplecooks.com/herby-tomato-flatbread-with-rye-cracker-crust/) which uses 50% rye and 50% whole wheat flour but replaced the wheat flour with rye. The 100% rye dough was perfect as a base and delicious. Same cooking times and everything. The recipe uses baking powder which cuts down on prep time as well.

Comment: Welcome! Please don’t post answers based on links - just imagine what would happen if the site you linked to disappeared.